# Ionic2 InAppBrowser

Tags: ionic2, inappbrowser

Hi I want to put a button in my page when clicked it will launch the website of the given item. However I got a problem and I don't know how to fix it. I just followed a recent tutorial online but unfortunately it didn't worked for me.

1.) This is the error appearing when I click on the button, circled in the image.
[image]

2.) Declaration of the constructor in the js file
[image]

[image]

3.) html button
[image]

4.) App version
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Add

```
import {InAppBrowser} from 'ionic-native';
```

Also I did not see this in your .js file

```
launch(url) {
    this.platform.ready().then(() => {
        open(url, "_blank", "location=no");
    });
}
```

This is required.

Answer (score 0):

Add
cordova plugin add cordova-inappbrowser
In your ts file just add this line under your imports and above your @component

declare var cordova ;

Once the platform is ready just add the below lines.
cordova.InAppBrowser.open(url, '_blank', 'location=yes')

Here is the example explained as how to open a browser in ionic-2.

https://www.thepolyglotdeveloper.com/2016/01/launch-websites-with-ionic-2-using-the-inappbrowser/